# CLion equivalent of Visual Studio C++ "filters"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clion, jetbrains-ide

## Context

In Visual Studio IDE, for C++ solutions, you can use so called "filters" to simulate source files tree/directories, while usually keeping all source code for each project in each project's root. Main merit being ability to directly `#include "foo.h"`

I've been trying to "switch" some solutions over to CLion, because of its multiplatform focus and trying to add support for CMake+GCC into already existing VS solutions, as no cross-platform IDE has native support for `.sln/.vcxproj` files

Now - I know that some larger CMake projects (as in solution/group of subprojects) often use plain filesystem subdirectories to further break-up its code in each subproject, but since some of "solutions" I'm trying to add CMake support to, consider of few hundred source files, I can't really go about refactoring everything manually and changing `#include "service_foo.h"` into `#include service/service_foo.h` in each of them.

Also another thing to consider is that I'm not migrating solution to work with CMake - I'm adding support for CMake builds/CLion IDE support alongside MSBuild toolchain/VS IDE support, so I don't want to introduce any breaking changes.

I'm still pretty new to JetBrains IDE ecosystem, so I wondered whether there is something that could provide this kind of functionality out of box, or perhaps with a plugin.

## Question

Is there any way to sort source files into groups without making on-filesystem changes, that is in project view toolbox in CLion IDE?

Couldn't find anything in documentation so far, but it would be something alike to [Code Hierarchy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/analyzing-applications.html), but for `.h/.cpp` files instead.

## Example

Filesystem-wise structure (as visible on-disk)
`$REPO_ROOT` is repository as provided with `*.vcxproj, .idea/` etc.

```
Main CMakeList.txt: $REPO_ROOT/CmakeList.txt
Example subprojects: $REPO_ROOT/foo_slib/ $REPO_ROOT/program/
Example Source files: $REPO_ROOT/program/main.cpp $REPO_ROOT/program/gui_init.h $REPO_ROOT/program/VulkanDelegate.h
```

Project/solution root-wise structure (as seen in project toolbox views in IDEs)
`$VIEW_ROOT` is main project open for CLion or .sln open for MSVS as seen in Project View in each IDE

```
Main CmakeList.txt: $VIEW_ROOT/CMAKE/CmakeList.txt
Example subprojects: $VIEW_ROOT/foo_slib/ $VIEW_ROOT/program/
Example Source files: $VIEW_ROOT/program/main.cpp $VIEW_ROOT/program/GUI/gui_init.h $VIEW_ROOT/program/Delegates/VulkanDelegate.h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely do NOT need to edit source files and change include paths. Nothing should be able to stop you from achieving the same `#include` paths with compiler [include path option, -`I<path>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html). In CLion, it's controlled through [CMake's target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) directive. You may also have to figure out how the projects are linked.

You can add files and folders to CLion's [favorites](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/favorites-tool-window.html). You can have multiple groups of favorites, so this can emulate arbitrary virtual folders in the project.

For a more elaborate query language, there are [Scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html#61824534). You can set them up, and then they will appear in the Views dropdown of the [Project view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#show-filesize-timestamp), each as a separate View.

Comment: `target_include_directories` doesn't seem like what I want, since that would require changes in MSVS solution/projects aswell, 
since from what I understand it's same as VS's C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories,
which would require changes in filesystem (sorting code in subproject to subdirectories, breaking paths of files stored in `.vcxproj`)

I was under impression `add_subdirectory` is strictly for adding a new subproject and can't be used to simply sort code - correct me if I'm wrong

I added example for what I'm trying to achieve here, see updated question

Comment: You seem to have an assumption that forces you to edit include paths, either in source files or in project files. That assumption is wrong. If VS can have a set of include paths (that's what the project does), then CMake file can do the same include paths too. You can even use VS project to figure out exactly what include paths each project uses.

Comment: I've deleted the `add_subdirectory` reference, as it's not what you need here (yet), but mentioned a "favorites" feature, which seems much closer to what the question is asking about.

Comment: Favorites seems to be what I have been looking for, but sadly there doesn't seem to be an option to nest them as in fav_dir/fav_subdir/*.cpp etc.       

I know I can add whole folders, but that doesn't really fit what I'm trying to do as I have folder per subproject structure and just want to sort code in each subproject instead.       

Do you know whether there is a way to nest them on IDE's side (I guess I could make directories with symlinks to source files only and add these to  favorites to simulate nesting, but that's a lot of manual work)

Comment: Well, file symlinks won't work since code insight doesn't work properly as it reads symlink location instead of opening file pointed at (it is way too hacky anyway), making the whole point of IDE gone. And I really can't find anything about nesting favorites at all, so if there is any plugin or anything that you know of, that makes nesting possible I would appreciate that

Comment: Finally, I recalled a feature that may satisfy the requirements: Scopes. Updated the answer.

Comment: I managed to setup something of reminiscence to Visual Studio filters, by combining all your suggestions together and without any changes in source structure itself (kind of), granted it was a pretty manual process.
Will probably make automatic script out of this and deploy on other projects, since it's way to manual as it is now. 
Explanation/solution to what I did added as another answer - I would have prefered something in IDE out-of-box though, not to pollute repository too much, but this was the least polluting solution I could come up with at the moment. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, if someone else needs this functionality

## Solution

Let's say all your MSVS projects(targets) are stored in root of `./src/` (`./` being repo root) on directory-per-project basis

1. Make sibling directory at repo root, say `./src_cmake/`
2. Make directory per projects stored in `./src/` at `./src_cmake/`, let's say we have made `./src_cmake/libproj/` corresponding to `./src/libproj/`
3. Taking `libproj` as example, make subdirectories in `./src_cmake/libproj/` corresponding to your **filter** tree structure for that project in Visual Studio
4. In each **filter subdirectory**, create file symlinks to source files corresponding to each file inside filter, let's say `Solution>libproj>Debugonly>` in Visual Studio
   contains `debmeta.h debmeta.cpp debutil.h`, that would require 3 new symlink files to be created at `./src_cmake/libproj/Debugonly/`, let's take debmeta.h for an example
5. You can create symlinks with `ln -s ORIGINALFILE LINKTARGET`, so while in shell opened at `./src_cmake/libproj/Debugonly/` use command

```
// This will navigate 3 directories down to repo root and from there to debmeta relative path
ln -s ../../../src/libproj/debmeta.h debmeta.h
```

6. This would be very prone to breaking (ex. renaming project in future), and could require restoring perhaps hundred of symlinks. To at least negate that, you can do this instead

```
// Shell open at ./src_cmake/libproj/ instead
ln -s ../../src/libproj .link
cd Debugonly

// Now use the .link folder so all links will be routed through it instead
ln -s ../.link/debmeta.h debmeta.h

// From now on use .link folder instead to navigate to original project directory, in case of breaking changes like new name of this subproject (at ./src_cmake/libproj/)
rm .link
ln -s ../../renamedsrc/renamedproj .link

// This way you shouldn't have to worry about cmake tree breakage
```

7. If you did everything, you should end up with `./src_cmake/` tree looking like your Visual Studio Project View tree
8. Now in `./CMakeList.txt` add subprojects as goes, you should call `add_subdirectory()` to each project individually, for Clion to correctly pick up targets like in example

```
add_subdirectory(src_cmake/libproj)
add_subdirectory(src_cmake/exeproj)
```

9. For each subproject in `./src_cmake/` you should add new *CMakeList* somehow corresponding to `.vcxproj` from `./src/`, so as example goes - `./src_cmake/libproj/CMakeList.txt`
10. In each such *CMakeList* add `target_include_directories()` and include all filter subdirectories for this project, going by example

```
target_include_directories(libproj
    PRIVATE Debugonly
)
```

11. Now since you most likely didn't do any of that manually (as explained below), you will probably provide script to generate filter structures and symlinks
    for `./src_cmake/` instead shipping folder as is, meaning you do not want to track anything besided CMakeList.txt for `./src_cmake/` and want to ignore symlinks from polluting your version control (VSC)
    as these would cause duplicates in code changes
    To prevent that create additional `.gitignore` at `./src_cmake/` as goes

```
# Choose which one better fits your needs, but first one should be prefered

# Ignore everything other than CMakeList.txt
*
!*/
!CMakeList.txt

# Or only ignore source code (in case of C/++
*.c
*.cpp
*.h
```

12. This way you should have setup everything filesystem side, now in Clion IDE Project Toolbox you will setup scope (equilavent of Solution Filters `.slnf` from Visual Studio)
13. Now in `Edit scopes>Add(+)>Shared>` only *Include Recursively* these paths `./src_cmake/ ./CMakeList.txt` (you can of course include/exclude other thing like .gitignore to your liking)
14. Now switch to your new scope and you should have end up with something that could pass for a Project View from Visual Studio C++

XX. Think of *CMakeList* in repo root somehow of `.sln` file and *CmakeList* in project folders as each `.vcxproj`, that is don't pollute root *CMakeList* with project local configuration
This way keeping both MSVS and CMake in sync, should be easier

Noone should do all of that manually though, so you could make a simple script going like that:

1. Pass `$SRCROOT` (MSVS Project Directory) so `./src` and `$OUTROOT` (CMake Project Directory) so `./src_cmake`
2. For each subdirectory at `$SRCROOT` create directory at `$OUTROOT` with name taken from `.vcxproj`, and make symlink in each of theme like this `$OUTROOT/$VCXPROJNAME/.link->$CD` (preferably relative path if you can calculate one)
3. Using xml parser for `.vcxproj` in each subfolder/project, get every `<ClInclude>` property and corresponding to it `<Filter>` value - create relative path of such if doesn't exist at `$OUTROOT/$VCXPROJNAME/$FilterVal`
4. For each of these `<ClInclude>` properties create symlink file from value provided and as link target use relative path to `.link` such as `$OUTROOT/$FilterVal/$ClIncludeVal->$(.link)/$ClIncludeVal`
5. This should simulate filter structure at `$OUTROOT` and from there you could just recursively iterate through it, generating basic `CMakeList.txt` for each subproject/target with just `target_include_directories()` and source file paths